# Create random numbers and store them in array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to let the user guess the random numbers then check how many he got concretely, please help.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace lab_12
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {    
            Random random = new Random();

            int[] num = new int[7];

            for (int i  = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
            {
                num[i] = random.Next(10);

                Console.Write(num[i]);
            }

            Thread.Sleep(4000);
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("type your answer");
            string temp = Console.ReadLine();
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(temp);                
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: What is the question or problem you have on your app? Please clearly provide your question.

Comment: Welcome to SO please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you want?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random random = new Random();

    int[] num = new int[7];

    for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
    {
        num[i] = random.Next(10);

        Console.Write(num[i]);
    }

    Thread.Sleep(4000);
    Console.Clear();
    int correctCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
    {
        bool canParse;
        int answer;
        do
        {
            Console.Write($"{i + 1}. Type your answer: ");
            canParse = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out answer);
        }
        while (!canParse);
        if (num[i] == answer)
        {
            correctCount++;
            Console.WriteLine("Correct. Go Next");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"You are wrong. Result is {num[i]}");
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"You answered {correctCount} out of {num.Length} correctly");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```